# ¿Los e.HResult de las excepciones en c# son unicos?

Tags: c#, webservice, excepciones

Quiero saber s cada e.HResult que da una excepción es unico y que como tal siempre es el mismo.

O si no ¿como podria validar una excepción especifica siempre?, mi problema es que necesito una excepción la cual me dice que no es posbile conectarse a internet(resumidamente) y el e.HResult siempre es -2146233087 pero no se si este e.HResult siempre es el mismo o pueda cambiar

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Segun microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult(v=vs.110).aspx):

> HRESULT es un valor de 32 bits, dividido en tres campos diferentes: un
>   código de gravedad, un código de instalación y un código de error. El
>   código de gravedad indica si el valor de retorno representa
>   información, advertencia o error. El código de instalación identifica
>   el área del sistema responsable del error. El código de error es un
>   número único que se asigna para representar la excepción. **Cada
>   excepción se asigna a un HRESULT distinto.**

Fijate que dice a cada exception, no a cada tipo de exception lo que es diferente. En tu caso siempre retornan los mismo codigos porque estas retornando el mismo error sobre las mismas circunstancias lo que provoca que siempre se cree el mismo codigo. Ahora bien, si las circunstancias varían, entonces el código de error seria diferente.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT) explica en mas detalle que significa cada porcion del codigo.

Asi que yo que tu, me fiara del tipo del a excepcion, no del codigo `HRESULT`.

Comment: Gracias!!!
La forma mas facil y a mi forma de ver la mas profesional seria crear un catch especial para cuando la excepción es el tipo que yo necesito, como se explica en este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715380/how-to-get-type-of-exception-in-c-sharp

Muchas Gracias